# QObject that waits for a specific call from outside (async result wrapper similar to QFuture)

Tags: c++, qt, asynchronous, mutex, thread-synchronization

I want to write a class (QObject-derived) that can wait for someone calling a specific function. This class will then be used to hold the result of an asynchronous operation (behind the scenes it's a remote procedure call). The interface of the class should look like the following:

```
class Result : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Result(...);

signals:
    void done();

public slots:
    void setDone(const QVariant & result);

    // blocking functions to receive the result
    void waitForFinished();
    QVariant result() { waitForFinished(); return _result; }

private:
    QVariant result;
    ...
}
```

Of course, this class should be **thread-safe**, meaning that

- the thread waiting for the result can be different than the one calling `setDone`
- multiple threads can request the result

Maybe this can be done with a QFuture. However, even if it is, I also **want to implement such a mechanism by myself** once in order to learn thread synchronization in Qt. If you know how to do it with QFuture, you can drop a comment.

What I came up with is the following. I additionally inherited from `QMutex` to have a mechanism similar to Java's `synchronize(this)`. Also, I added a `bool _done` member:

```
void Result::Result(...) :
    QObject(...),
    _done(false)
{
}

void Result::setDone(const QVariant & result)
{
    QMutexLocker synchronize(this);
    _result = result;
    _done = true;
    emit done();
}

void Result::waitForFinished()
{
    QMutexLocker synchronize(this);

    if (!_done) {
        QEventLoop loop;
        connect(this, SIGNAL(done()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
        loop.exec();
    }
}
```

Is this a correct implementation?

Another solution a friend of mine came up with was to lock the mutex in the constructor, marking the result *not to be done*. In `setDone`, unlock the mutex, and in `waitForFinished` use a wait condition to wait for the mutex to get unlocked. I never used `QWaitCondition`, so I don't know if this does what I want.

Comment: When a function calls `waitForFinished`, it locks the mutex, and therefore the function `setDone` will never be allowed to emit done, as it also wants to lock the mutex... deadlock!

Comment: Look at QFutureWatcher: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qfuturewatcher.html